# Using jQuery promise to simulate synchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've been using the [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com) library, which operates asynchronously, but I have a need to use it in a synchronous way (for example, putting up a "confirm" window before submitting a form).

**I don't want to use `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the event**, I want to defer the action until the user has responded to the modal. Currently the library doesn't support it, but I am curious if synchronous behavior could be simulated by using promises?

Here's a very basic example, using a link (instead of a form submit button, which is my final goal):
http://plnkr.co/edit/5NovsuKTeQ7y6SKNTwWp?p=preview

Comment: I think the way you have done it is the way it should be done. Do you mean it's ugly because you are using a dialog box instead of html?

Comment: @weeknie - which way? The way I am using the first link, it doesn't wait for the modal-- this is where I think promises might be able to help simulate the synchronicity of the 2nd link.

Comment: What you could do is instead of using a form that submit, use directly the modal and when the user clicks the "confirm" of the modal then you could capture the data and do what you wanted with it.
Or you could check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205044/how-to-make-a-modal-confirmation-dialog-before-submitting-a-form

Comment: Interesting -- so you're suggesting making the button/link/whatever element on the page just call the modal, then inside the modal make the OK/Yes button have the actual event? I think I'd have to make a custom dialog to do it this way, which is why I was hoping to use promises or some other way to delay the default action.

Comment: Here is a working solution for bootbox [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394453/14697989](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394453/14697989)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not what promises do at all. Promises would be unable to help you here.

The default action for a link is to navigate away to another page (or go to a section in this page). If you want to prevent a link from doing its thing - you *have* to use `e.preventDefault()` or return false from a `onclick` handler (preferably the former).

`preventDefault` is *exactly* what you need and sounds exactly like your goal.

#### But `confirm` works?!

Yes, it does, no one really knows why - blocking was the original behavior of `confirm` `prompt` and `alert` and it was never changed for backwards compatibility. It completely blocks and nothing happens while it's up - this is unlike the language and other APIs and is very uncharacteristic. - For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert("World");
},100);
alert("Hello");
```

Here, `"World"` will not be aleterd until you close the "Hello" box even though it only has a 100 ms timeout. `alert`s and `prompt`s simply 'freeze' JavaScript execution. They're considered bad user experience and are generally a poor choice except for very specific problems.

#### So what are promises?

Promises are an abstraction over deferred computation, they allow you to create asynchronous code that looks like it was synchronous which is awesome, but they're not magical and they don't turn the code to be *actually* synchronous. All promises do is make coding asynchronous code almost *as easy* as writing synchronous code.

Comment: OK-- the form submit request has a lot of parameters coming along with it. Is there a way to grab this complex action (maybe from `e`) and "save" it for later?

Comment: @pennstatephil you can call `submit()` on a form yourself. `document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit()` :)

Comment: the submit button has a param on it (multiple submits on the form for "save" vs "commit" for example), but I think I can grab that param and throw it into the request later. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You can also use a closure and put that code inside the request - no harm in that. The problem here is that preventDefault() is a synchronous call and submitting the form with a modal confirmation is asynchronous.

Comment: I've used this before, but it wasn't working for a particular case I was running into on a colleague's site: https://gist.github.com/pennstatephil/9896793

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and one solution i've found is to use an hidden button :

```
<button id="submit" type="submit" style="display:none;">x</button>
<button id="send_submit" type="button">y</button>
```

Then in js code,

```
$("#send_submit").click(function(e){
    bootbox.confirm("Really want to do this ?", function(result){
        if(result)
            $("#submit").click();
    })
})
```

That's not a beautiful method, but it's work like you want, other way is like you said, use the prevenDefault on event, and catch all the incoming data one by one to send them with .post;

Answer (score 0):

I had this question also using Bootbox. This is how I solved it.

Take a look to this Delete form:

```
<form action="route/to/action" method="POST">
  <!-- these two instructions depend on your framework -->
  @method('DELETE')
  @csrf

  <!-- The submit button in the form, change it to type="button". -->
  <!-- This prevent the form submission without the user's confirmation. -->
  <button type="button" id="delete" title="Delete element">
    Delete
  </button>
</form>
```

Then, add a click event listener to call the `submit()` event programatically.

```
  let deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete');

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    bootbox.confirm('Delete this element?', (confirma) => {
      if (confirma) {
        return $(ev.target)[0].form.submit(); 
      }
    })
  });
```